# bash for loop variable with awk

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, after being mostly searching for solutions and reading posts.  I am trying to run a loop using bash so I can do the string search over a bunch of different files with the ext .u.clean  I want to look through these files for the string "H#" or "h#" with the # being 1-28, and outputting to a file with the number that was searched for in the string.  I am doing two separate searches in two fields ($5 and $0) and I wanted to output the total number of unique matches to a file "temp"#.txt.  After this I want to do some math on the two numbers that are input in the file.  So far I have gotten this far:

```bsh
for i in {1..28}; do
    awk -v var="$i" -F"\t"  ' $19 ~ "_[hH]"var {print $0}' */*.u.clean | \
        sort | uniq | wc -l > 'temp'$i'.txt' | \
        awk -v var="$i" -F"\t"  ' $19 ~ "_[hH]"var {print $5}' */*.u.clean | \
        sort | uniq | wc -l >> 'chris'$i'.txt'
done
```

The problem is that the numbers are coming out wrong.  I am getting a total of 28 "temp"#".txt" files, but the inputs are not the correct word count numbers.  I also dont know how to do a mathematical operation one I have the files with the numbers in them.  Can someone help me out or point me to the right direction?  Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Here is what some of the input might look like:

> 112     E       03      294168  FBLN7_rs335586251.5     G       G
>   01/23/2013      2       3       VSD control 130123_CR_CH5_H26       1 
>   A.Conservative
>
> 17      D       11      294319  FBLN7_rs335586251.5     G       G
>   06/26/2012      2       3       VSD control
>   120626_CR_CH5_H3        1       A.Conservative
>
> 22      B       01      294703  FBLN7_rs335586251.5     G       G
>   06/26/2012      2       2       VSD control
>   120626_CR_CH5_H4        1       A.Conservative
>
> 103     A       07      295033  FBLN7_rs335586251.5     G       G
>   01/23/2013      2       1       VSD control
>   130123_CR_CH5_H23       1       A.Conservative
>
> 44      G       07      295119  Tbx5_rs61931008.5     G       G
>   07/11/2012      2       5       ASD control
>   120711_CR_CH5_H12       1       A.Conservative
>
> 42      H       12      295201  JAG1_rs1232607.5      G       G
>   07/11/2012      1       2       ASD control
>   120711_CR_CH5_H12       1       A.Conservative

I am trying to find a count of how many times in field 19 ( the field with the text Tbx5_rs61931008.5.), each occurence of H'#' occurs with # being from 1-28, output that number to a separate file for each H#.  Then I want to know withing these matches of H#, how many unique occasions of field 5 there are, and output that number to the same file for each H#.  I hope this is clear, and let me know id it is not.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please update your question with some input as well as expected output as it will make it much easier to answer your question? Welcome to SO BTW :-)

Comment: The `wc -l >file | awk ...` part of the pipeline is obviously wrong; do you mean `wc -l >file; awk ...` instead? You cannot redirect to a file and continue the pipeline at the same time (except with something like `wc -l | tee file | awk ...` if that's what you really want).

Comment: Unfortunately it's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to do, but there are is at least one suspicious looking thing going on: You say you are `...doing two separate searches in two fields ($5 and $0) ` in fact you are just printing $0 and $5 your search runs over field $19 _both_ times. EDIT: didn't spot the `>` issue mentioned in the comment above - guess that's your main problem then.

Comment: You should add comments to your script. By doing that you will be forced to think about what each step is doing and so uncover most of the problems with it yourself. After that re-post here if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit complicated for what you are trying to achieve.  I would suggest using `find` and `grep`

```
find . -name "*.u.clean" -exec egrep -c '([Hh][1-9])|([Hh][1-2][0-9])'
```

You have to take the output and do the math

This assumes there is only one `h#` per line in the file, if this is not correct then you will need to do a little more work.  I would find all the files that have any occurrences and then use `egrep -o '([Hh][1-9])|([Hh][1-2][0-9])' | wc -l` to get the total for each file.

Comment: I want to count the total number of each occurrence of H1-H28, not the total. Thanks.